# Generate dates onclick in datepicker

Tags: javascript, input, datepicker, onclick

I'm using "datepicker" script and I've created a link that generates a series of dates on click.

**Javascript**

```
function change(){
    document.getElementById('datepicker').value='06/10/2022,20/10/2022,17/11/2022';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="test" class="datepicker" placeholder="select dates"><br>
<a href="#" onclick="change()">link</a>
```

On click on the link, these dates **appear in the input field**, but **in the calendar these dates are not enabled**...
They become enabled if I put the cursor in my input field and I have an action like "Ctrl+A" for example.

Does anyone have any idea ? thank you so much ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dates replace text "link" on click you should set `id="datepicker"` on your anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution :

**Javascript**

```
function change(){
$('#datepicker').val('06/10/2022,20/10/2022,17/11/2022').datepicker('update');
}
```